# In JavaScript, what are the performance costs of boxing every number and string on objects?

Tags: javascript, performance, hash, lisp

I am programming a Lisp like language on JavaScript for learning purposes. Every object is part of a tree so it must keep track of its parent. The only problems are numbers and strings:

```
foo = {};
var a = 1;
a.parent = foo;
```

This will not work. I have to do this instead:

```
foo = {};
var a = {type:'number',value:1,parent:foo}
```

So I would have to box every number and string on my language in a hash like that. I pretend to do some extensive matrix math on said language, so I am worried. Would this approach be a hit on performance?

Comment: Of course it will be a hit. Whether or not that hit matters is another question entirely. I'd recommend writing some sample code and benchmarking it to see if its performance is acceptable. It is nigh impossible to judge whether or not something performs acceptably just by reading the code, and you should not fall prey to micro-optimizations.

Comment: That is a good idea. But why voting to close? This is not very localized, at all. Knowing the performance costs of hashes is very broad in a language where hashes are everywhere.

Comment: I'm not the one who voted to close. Honestly, the performance hit is going to vary depending on where the bulk of the time spent in your code is. Setting up the objects is probably trivial compared to your matrix math, but at the same time, doing the property accessors on the objects in the matrix math may not be too bad at all. Honestly, you will just have to benchmark it and see if it performs to your needs, and if not, come back and ask another question on how to improve it.

Comment: In this case you could test with arrays (with numeric indexes, 0=parent, 1=type, 3=value). I haven't benchmarked but I expect the lookup to be a little faster, but it might be so little that it isn't noticeable.

Comment: I have ran some tests, put it here as an answer. Definitely not a good idea. How can I keep track of the parent relationship otherwise?

Comment: @Dokkat It depends on what you want to do.  Is the explicit parent relationship really necessary?  You could represent trees top-down instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Reid suggested:

```
function number(n){
    return {type:'number',parent:undefined,value:n};
}
function sum(a,b){
    return {type:'number',parent:undefined,value:a.value+b.value};
}
var i = number(0);
for (var t=Date.now(); Date.now()-t < 1000;){
    var i=sum(i,number(1));}
console.log('Operations with boxing: ',i.value);
var i = 0;
for (var t=Date.now(); Date.now()-t < 1000;){
    var i=i+1;}
console.log('Operations without boxing: ',i);
```

Output:

```
Operations with boxing: 1911258
Operations without boxing: 16805783
```

This probably answers the question. I wonder if there is an alternative that won't be such a performance hit.

Comment: For performance testing, I suggest http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Nice. http://jsperf.com/calculations-after-boxing-numbers-inside-an-object

Comment: it should be Number() not number()